# iOS dismissModalViewController results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, modalviewcontroller

Calling dismissModalViewController will intermittently cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESs.

The intermittency is related to the specific build, not the specific run. That is, if the executable has been compiled, the call will either consistently pass or consistently fail.

It does not seem to depend on whether the code has even changed between builds.

We're using the iPhone 5.1 simulator and an iPod touch 4th gen with iOS 5.1 installed. This behaviour is present in both the simulated and physical device

Has anyone seen this before? We're at our wit's end.

Here's both where the modal view controller gets presented as well as where it gets dismissed:

```
PaymentStack* paymentStack = 
[[PaymentStack alloc] initWithOrder:[anOrderManager thisOrder] locationState:[appData locationState]
                       successBlock:^{
                           //Push the current order on the history list
                           [[appData ordersHistory] addObject:[anOrderManager thisOrder]];
                           if ([[anOrderManager thisOrder] isEffectivelyEqual:[anOrderManager thisOrder]])
                           {
                               //Allocate a new order
                               [anOrderManager setOrder:[[Order alloc] init]];
                           }
                       }
                    completionBlock:^{

                        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
                                                 completion:^{
                                                     NSLog(@"Complete.");
                                                 }];
                    }
                  cancellationBlock:^{
                      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
                                               completion:^{
                                                   NSLog(@"Cancellation.");
                                               }];
                  }];
[self presentModalViewController:[paymentStack navigationController] animated:YES];
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
#0  0x00d659ab in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] ()
#1  0x00b4ea9c in -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] ()
#2  0x00b4df91 in -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] ()
#3  0x00b4ec81 in -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:] ()
#4  0x00071135 in __35-[MasterViewController placeOrder:]_block_invoke_0186 at /Users/jake/Documents/Avocado/AvocadoTest1.0/MasterViewController.m:258
#5  0x000515c0 in __91-[PaymentStack initWithOrder:locationState:successBlock:completionBlock:cancellationBlock:]_block_invoke_0 ()
#6  0x000545c8 in __27-[PaymentStack showSuccess]_block_invoke_0230 ()
#7  0x000558cc in -[PaymentCompleteViewController done] ()
#8  0x01a47e99 in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] ()
#9  0x00a8214e in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
#10 0x00cc0a0e in -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] ()
#11 0x01a47e99 in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] ()
#12 0x00a8214e in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
#13 0x00a820e6 in -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] ()
#14 0x00b28ade in -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] ()
#15 0x00b28fa7 in -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] ()
#16 0x00b28266 in -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
#17 0x00aa73c0 in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
#18 0x00aa75e6 in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
#19 0x00a8ddc4 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#20 0x00a81634 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#21 0x03dd9ef5 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#22 0x01a1a195 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#23 0x0197eff2 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#24 0x0197d8da in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#25 0x0197cd84 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#26 0x0197cc9b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#27 0x03dd87d8 in GSEventRunModal ()
#28 0x03dd888a in GSEventRun ()
#29 0x00a7f626 in UIApplicationMain ()
#30 0x000025ed in main at /Users/jake/Documents/Avocado/AvocadoTest1.0/AvocadoTest1/main.m:16
```

If there's a better way that I can format this for you, let me know.

Comment: Okay, I'll go post that for you.

Comment: Could you please show the stack trace? Have you tried running a profiler with zombies, or a static analyzer?

Comment: Yeah, I'll get the stack trace for you. We've run it with zombies. To be honest, I'm not the most iOS savvy person on our dev team, but my co-worker ran it with zombies, and apparently it didn't tell him anything.

Comment: Did you manage to work this problem out? We are facing it right now and would appreciate a pointer.

Comment: I'm running into this too. Using a UIImagePickerController seems to be the issue that causes this to happen. If I display a UIImagePickerController, and then later (unrelated to the UIImagePickerController), I present a view controller and dismiss it with dismissViewControllerAnimated, I consistently get this kind of crash.

Comment: The issue is occurring on iOS7.1.2 but not on iOS6.

Answer (score 1):

When you run something like:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
                         completion:^{
                                     NSLog(@"Complete.");
                                     }];
```

inside a block and run something like:

```
[self presentModalViewController:[paymentStack navigationController] animated:YES];
```

outside of the block it's impossible to know which line of code will run first. Sometimes it will be the dismissViewControllerAnimated:, other times it will be the presentModalViewController:.

If the dismissViewControllerAnimated: runs first then the viewController is probably getting dealloc'ed so when the app tries to run the presentModalViewController: it is sending a message to an object that no longer exists and that is probably the cause of the crash.

Good luck!

Comment: That would definitely be a good guess, but unfortunately the callback blocks are triggered by UI events that involve interaction with the view controller. They can only happen if the view has finished being presented.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I was having (with the same symptoms as this) turned out to be (after a solid day of debugging!) the following situation:

1) View controller A presents (using presentViewController:animated:completion:) view controller B.

2) View controller B keeps a weak reference to view controller A (delegate reference).

3) View controller B executes a method on view controller A which, as a side effect, deallocates view controller A.

4) View controller B tries to dismiss itself using:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:completion];
```

Part of the difficulty in tracking this down arose from step 3) being asynchronous. Step 4) was occurring and step 3) hadn't finished yet. I.e., view controller B was deallocated part way through step 4).

Answer (score 0):

Try to save 2 strong pointers: one to PaymentStack viewController and one to "self". It will help to detect who was destroyed. 
Add "- (void)dealloc" methods for every viewControllers and add break points to these methods. It will help to detect the point of destroying.